# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy with external identity provider Error AADB2C90289

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework, aad-b2c

I have successfully configured an external identity provider using Azure AD B2C Custom policy. The authorize endpoint is passed correct acr_values too. As I launch the authorize endpoint, I am taken to the login screen from identity provider. As soon as I enter my credentials and hit 'Login',I expect the authentication response to be redirected to my B2C /auth/resp URL (https://<>.b2clogin.com/<>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp), configured with the identity provider.
However, I end up getting an exception as below -
AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.
Correlation ID: ef54294f-2a9d-4e18-bc03-511bcc713cde
Timestamp: 2022-10-10 04:04:09Z

AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.
Correlation ID: 42dc0316-16d5-4f5b-9552-6cc4d2f3e233
Timestamp: 2022-10-10 09:38:51Z

I have also tried verifying the client_id and client_secret being used and that seems to be fine. Moreover, logs on the identity provider side mention that the request was successful.

Awaiting quick responses, as this blocks my application completely.

Application Insights details -

Exception Message:An internal error has occurred., CorrelationID:145303ec-b8e8-4fc1-bd5d-6649bd1fb77f

Comment: Have you looked at the logs using App. Insights?

Comment: Yes have configured app insights too.......but only get too see 'An internal error has ocurred' with a correlation id like below. No more details in it.

Comment: Exception Message:An internal error has occurred., CorrelationID:864c1bd5-adc1-4530-bd69-83afaf00602a

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

This error ,  `AADB2C90289: We encountered an error “” connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.`   occurred ,

when I haven’t given the clientSecret of the app correctly in the azure ad b2c.
I kept it to generate.

- Later I manually changed the `policy keys` and gave the application client secret in the key value.

[image]

In your external Identity provider technical profile, make sure to -provide the clientId of that particular Identity provider

Ex:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
  <Metadata>
  <!Below replace clientId with the externalIdentity provider App/ClientId "-->
    <Item Key="client_id">XXX0000XXX</Item>

      ....
```

[image]